# Why would a domain have "clientTransferProhibited" status without "ok"?

Tags: domains

What does it mean when a domain has status "clientTransferProhibited" and no other domain status indicated in Whois?  An example at the present moment would be "mcknight.us" (this is a current example, but not the one I'm interest in).  It seems to be just past the "addPeriod".  If it has no "ok" status (as a normally registered domain would), and has no status indicating renewal, pending deletion, or any kind of grace period, then what is its actual status?  What is happening?

(edit to add...)  To clarify my question:  What is the difference between a domain having exactly one Domain Status line, that being "clientTransferProhibited", and a domain having exactly two Domain Status lines, those being "clientTransferProhibited" and "ok"?

Answer (score 1):

> To clarify my question: What is the difference between a domain having exactly one Domain Status line, that being "clientTransferProhibited", and a domain having exactly two Domain Status lines, those being "clientTransferProhibited" and "ok"?

That shouldn't happen (the second case).

The EPP specifications at RFC 5731 are pretty clear, in §2.3 :

> - ok
>
> ```
>  This is the normal status value for an object that has no pending
>  operations or prohibitions.  This value is set and removed by the
>  server as other status values are added or removed.
> ```

Basically `ok` should be the EPP status that appear if there is no other statuses. And if there is another status, then `ok` should not appear.

Comment: OK, thanks, I get it now...  "ok" is removed when there are any prohibitions at all, including clientTransferProhibited (I had assume "ok" was there for all normally-working domains, but I see that it specifically means no prohibitions at all, nor pending operations).

Comment: TBH, I don't feel the specification did it right regarding this, but it is what it is. Note that there is also an `inactive` status, for domains without nameservers, and supposedly this would remove `ok` too. Anyway in all registry/registrar codes I have seen or developed, it is either `ok` alone, or any other combination of other ones but not `ok`.  Of course, you can find other variations in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a lock by the Registrar, but it can be removed.

> clientTransferProhibited
> client transfer prohibited
>
> This status code tells your domain's registry to reject requests to transfer the domain from your current registrar to another.

[EPP Status Codes from ICANN](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/epp-status-codes-2014-06-16-en)

> REGISTRAR-LOCK is a status code that can be set on an Internet domain name by the sponsoring registrar of the domain name. This is usually done in order to prevent unauthorized, unwanted or accidental changes to the domain name.

[What does domain status clientTransferProhibited mean?](https://wise-answer.com/what-does-domain-status-clienttransferprohibited-mean/)

**Note**

All my 9 domains show the **clientTransferProhibited**, without the ok status.  There is, no second line.  And I believe it shows **clientTransferProhibited** because I have disabled the **Sell My Domain** flag.